# Где должны располагаться widgets в Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Где должны располагаться widgets в Yii2? В какой директории, чет читал про них в официальной документации и ничего не нашел по этому поводу? Даже в структуре приложения нету такой папки или которая относится к ним.  А точнее, похоже они должны располагаться в "View/Wigets", но я не уверен.

Comment: Как написал @kroder  можно расположить где-угодно главное неймспейсы указывать.... просто виджеты состоят из двух частей - контроллера и представления...поэтому будет как минимум папка `widgets` внутри которой будут контроллеры аля `ActionsWidget`, `MessageWidget` и т.д. а также в этой же папке желательно создать папку `views` для расположения представлений для этих самых виджетов где будут лежать например `actions.php`, `message.php` и т.д.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  я так понимаю, раз Widget состоит и из контроллеров, то будет правильным создать  папку - "controllers" для них?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский А стоит ли навиганионную панельку сайта, делать в виде веджета?

Comment: Светлов `будет правильным создать папку - "controllers"`- это по желанию.Если посмотреть в контроллер виджета-там будет написано типа `class ActionsWidget extends Widget` а не `class ActionsWidgetController extends Widget`. смотрите, чтоб себя самого не запутать. ИМХО проще следовать рекомендованным соглашениям так сказать, т.е. в корне сайта вместе с остальными папками висит папка `widgets` в ней папка `views` для представлений, а в корне папки `widgets` контроллеры....А навпанель - всё зависит от задач..всегда.. у многих она тупо в layout'e ибо и не используется нигде больше

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Понятно, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какого-то места, где прямо должны - нет, собственно это относится и ко всем остальным сущностям. Структура basic/advanced app - это просто предлагаемый пример, которому можно следовать. А так можно просто в компоненты сунуть, можно и в свою какую-то диру, если их предполагается несколько или хочется красоты. Главное неймспейсы задавать соответственно файловой структуре, чтобы автолоад эти классы подхватывал. Т.е. если класть в /widgets, то и неймспейс у классов будет app\widgets, ну или какой он там вместо app у вас задан.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. Если я написал nav_bar на (сss, js, html5), мне его стоит использовать в виде виджета? Я пока не могу дать четкого определение виджетов, а конкретно их предназначение.

Comment: ну заворачивать в виджет есть смысл, если он где-то еще будет переиспользован. а просто так все в виджеты сидеть заворачить - это странная затея)